# How to build a fingerprint identifying app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, fingerprint

I want to create a mobile app where users can identify their presence through finger print.

So the steps would be:

1. Register user fingerprints
2. Show a fingerprint icon where users can place their finger on
3. Identify the fingerprint of the user with the registered finger prints of the app

Is this possible? I only see fingerprint authentication, with linked fingerprints on the system.

I prefer to create this in a React Native environment. Because I don't have a lot of experience with Android/iOS native development.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In theory you could try to do this with photos of the users fingers, but I doubt that the device camera has sufficient resolution for this with the finger at a distance and wouldn't be able to focus close enough for a close up scan of a finger.

Comment: have you checked this repository? https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain

Comment: You can try this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fingerprint-scanner